# Re-Direct Empty WooCommerce Search Result To Custom Page

Tags: php, redirect, woocommerce, template-redirect

I am trying to achieve a re-direct to a custom URL for all product search results that return a 0 result. With the code below I get "`Fatal error`" message screen in WordPress.

**This is my code:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_empty_search_result', 2 );
function redirect_empty_search_result() {

    if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && strcasecmp( $_GET['s'] ) == 0 ) {
        
        wp_safe_redirect( '/empty-search/' );
    
    exit();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in the error log?   500 errors log debugging information about the problem, usually in the `error_log` produced by your web server.

Comment: I did miss one `)` in the code. So now it says this: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: strcasecmp() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given`

Comment: [According to the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) strcasecmp() compares two strings in a case-insensitive way. You are calling the function with only one string which is why you are getting the error.

Comment: You are currently checking if the `s` parameter - the _search term_ entered by the user - is equal to `0`. That is of course something completely different, than checking whether the search performed _using_ the value of `s`, returned zero results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked your code but "strcasecmp" requires two parameters
exmaple :

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_empty_search_result', 2 );
function redirect_empty_search_result() {

    if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && strcasecmp( $_GET['s'], '' ) == 0 ) {
    
        wp_safe_redirect( '/empty-search/' );
        exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that version as well, but it does not redirect.

Comment: what is your theme?

Comment: Where the code is used

Comment: Theme: bootscore
In the cild theme's functions file.

Comment: This code work for me by bootscore

Comment: Yes, that works. Which it shouldn't in my opinion. In other words, need to extend the search function to ignore blank searches.